# ¿Cómo unir varios proyectos java en un solo proyecto y visualizar?

Tags: java-8, netbeans-8.2

Estoy tratando de realizar un proyecto en el cual se debe mostrar 7 proyectos(cada uno con 3 o 4 clases), y elegir mediante un menú el proyecto a visualizar, lo estoy haciendo a nivel de paquete(uniendo todos los proyectos), pero no sé como hacer el llamado de los métodos main de todos los proyectos.

Por internet encontré este código pero no lo entiendo:

```
Method mainMethod = Class.forName(args[0]).getDeclaredMethod("main",argTypes);

Object[] argListForInvokedMain = new Object[1];
argListForInvokedMain[0] = new String[0];
mainMethod.invoke(null, argListForInvokedMain);
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que realizar el comando en la terminal, en la carpeta de donde esten los .java:

```
javac -d . Clase1.java Clase2.java Clase3.java
```

Este comando te genera una carpeta en tu directorio con los .class compilados.

Si por ejemplo quieres compilar el paquete recorridos y el main lo tienes en Arista.java. Te mueves a la carpeta de dentro del paquete recorrido(cd EstructuraPorta/src/recorridos) y después compilas los .java que necesites:

```
javac -d . Arista.java Mapa.java Nodo.java grafos.java
```

A continuacion ejecutas la clase con el main:

```
java recorridos.Arista
```

recorridos es el nombre de la carpeta creada y Arista es el nombre de la clase que contiene el main.
Esto sirve tanto para windows como linux. Solamente necesitas saber moverte en la terminal. Espero haber resuelto tu duda. Un saludo.